# How to return carriage to previous line in PHP

Tags: php

The `\r` will move my pointer to the begin of line, but how to return to previous line??

e.g. From code:

```
echo "First Line \n";
echo "Second Line \n";
ReturnToPreviousLine();
echo "Third Line \n";
```

executed by `$ php script.php`

I want to output in console:

```
Third Line
Second Line
```

---

Maybe I will add better example:

```
  echo "Hello World!\n"
  //some loop
    echo "Time        Percent\n";
    echo "\r$time       $percent";
  //end loop
  returnToPreviousLine();
  echo "Done                 \n";
  echo "                     \n";
```

Output during loop:

```
Hello World!
Time        Percent
00:00:10    10%
```

Output after loop:

```
Hello World!
Done
```

Comment: Man that's a very very interesting requirement :)

Comment: @ClémentMalet *"move my pointer to the begin of line"* just killed my attention. `:/` You're right.

Comment: Are you trying to write a console app that updates a screen, instead of just outputting line by line? Please clarify your use case so we can help you better.

Comment: Yes. I added better example for that.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this visual output using ANSI terminal control chars. I once wrote a library for this, it is on Github: [`Jm_Console`](https://github.com/metashock/Jm_Console). I suggest installing it using PEAR (because it will handle depencies for you)

Here comes an example on how to use it:

```
require_once 'Jm/Autoloader.php';

// Will refactor the Singleton pattern once :)
$console = Jm_Console::singleton();

// Save the cursor position before printing the first line
$console->savecursor();

// Output the first and second line
$console->writeln('First Line');
$console->writeln('Second Line');

// Sleep a second ...
sleep(1);

// Return back to the first line
$console->restorecursor();

// Erase the first line
$console->stdout()->eraseln();

// Print the third line (And the second line again, unfortunately)
$console->writeln('Third line');
$console->writeln('Second line');
```

Comment: Link to the library so we can get it ? ;)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thx :) Yeah, i like it too. It needs some refactoring because of the singleton pattern used in it. Feel free to post an issue request there if you miss something...

Comment: I know it begs the question, *"do we care?"* but just for clarification will it work in the Windows console?  In my - albeit limited - experience of console apps *ANSI* characters don't.

Comment: you need to install ansicon on windows. it is a cmd.exe replacement. (and the library will then support windows, it was one of the main design goals) https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon

Comment: I believe Symfony offers a pretty capable component for console UIs too: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice instructional example taken from https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/overwriting-command-line-output-php

```
function replaceCommandOutput(array $output) {
  static $oldLines = 0;
  $numNewLines = count($output) - 1;

  if ($oldLines == 0) {
    $oldLines = $numNewLines;
  }

  echo implode(PHP_EOL, $output);
  echo chr(27) . "[0G";
  echo chr(27) . "[" . $oldLines . "A";
}

while (true) {
  $output = [];
  $output[] = 'First Line';
  $output[] = 'Time: ' . date('r');
  $output[] = 'Random number: ' . rand(100, 999);
  $output[] = 'Random letter: ' . chr(rand(65, 89));
  $output[] = 'Last Line';
  replaceCommandOutput($output);
  usleep(100000);
}
```

To go to the start of the line use `echo chr(27) . "[0G";`

To go up a number of lines use `echo chr(27) . "[" . $numLines . "A";`

Answer (score -1):

You can give it a try with [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), AFAIK if you don't use it the moment you call `echo` you get your line, so you can't undo it.

So the trick is use output buffering and then prior to outputing it again, hook into the output to change what you want:

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo "First line\n";
echo "Second line\n";
echo "Third line\n";

$output = ob_get_clean();

$lines = explode("\n", $output);

print_r($lines);

// Outputs:
Array
(
    [0] => First line
    [1] => Second line
    [2] => Third line
    [3] =>
)
```

From here on you'll have your output in the $lines array, and then you can `echo` any line you want

Comment: Wow all that can be done in one line. `print_r(array("First Line", "Second Line", "Third Line"));`

Comment: Of course, but the idea is to be able to hook into any line (of any given output), if you have control over the array then there is no point even in the question, you just ouput in the order you want :-)

Comment: Wish the last line of your previous comment was the complete answer in itself, I would up-vote it 2 times if I could :)